# Intercept any creation of a third-party internal class to modify a property

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy

Firstly a bit of context. In my application I have a number of third party controls, one of these includes themes and style changes to normal WPF controls. The problem I have is that I also use a control from a different third party, within this control is an internal window.

The problem I have is that the first third party styles make the layout of this window all wrong.

What I am hoping to achieve is some way to intercept whenever this internal window is created and modify a property of it. If I can set the "ThemeName" property to "None" on this instance the style and layout of the window is fixed. I have tried and tested this using Snoop. I could also potentially intercept the Show() / ShowDialog() method of a Window and perform some checks?

From searching Castle seems to be recommend by all the examples I find require the class to configure which I can't do as it will fail to compile as the class is internal and therefore not accessible.

I'm not sure what code I can share unfortunately. I am able to get the type using Type.GetType which I can then use Activator.CreateInstance to create an instance, but I'm stuck on then setting the property and wiring up the interception.

I am not overly familiar with AOB.

Comment: What about using reflection to set given property?

Comment: @Selvin But how do I know when the instance of the internal class is created? That it is out of my control, which is why I believe I need to intercept it?

Comment: but you have parent class instance ... so find this internal class inside parent class instance ... even if it's private field in parent class you may access it via reflection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out I was drastically over complicating this and the actual fix turned out to be quite simple.

In the App.xaml.cs App() constructor I registered the following class handler to listen for any Window Loaded events.

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Window.LoadedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(WindowLoaded));
```

Then in that method I check the type of the Window and override the property as needed.

```
static void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender.GetType().Name.Contains("InternalWindowClassName"))
        ThemeManager.SetThemeName(sender as DependencyObject, Theme.NoneName);
}
```

Can also use

```
(sender as DependencyObject).SetValue(DependencyProperty, value);
```